# set borderRadius with resizeMode contain in react-native without knowing dimensions of image

Tags: react-native, frontend

Any ideas how to add borderRadius to the image that has resizeMode set to contain, and no knowledge of height and width?

The code currently looks like this, but this doesn't work.

```
<View
style={[
    styles.imageContainerWrapper,
    { width: width },
]}
key={i}
>
  <Image
      source={{ uri: url }}
      borderRadius={normalize(20)}
      resizeMode="contain"
      style={{
          height: '100%',
          maxWidth: '100%',
          maxHeight: '100%',
          overflow: 'hidden',
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
      }}
  />
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `borderRadius` to the style property of the Image like this:

```
<View
style={[
    styles.imageContainerWrapper,
    { width: width },
]}
key={i}
>
  <Image
      source={{ uri: url }}
      resizeMode="contain"
      style={{
          height: '100%',
          maxWidth: '100%',
          maxHeight: '100%',
          overflow: 'hidden',
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
          borderRadius: 20,
      }}
  />
```

Comment: This would work if the image wouldn't be set to contain.